# adding a new data column in a file consisting of 4 columns

Tags: shell, unix

I have two tab delimited files:
File 1: 12 rows and 1 column
File 2: 12 rows and 4 columns

I want to merge these two files i.e., I have a new file of 12 rows and 5 columns (last column should be from file 1.

Any suggestions for shell script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paste` for that:

```
paste file2 file1
```